# Which is the best application to create pixel art in Unity2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a video game in unity 2D but I need to know which are the best applications to create pixel art

Comment: The best one is the one you know. Other than that there are always compromises. Check the Aseprite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a short list of what came to my mind, it is by far not complete.

- You can use MS Paint with the Magnifier to create precise pixel art, but it does not support shadowing etc. If you use JPEG, every save-action will add more JPEG artifacts.
- Paint.net is free and powerful, a good alternative to the limited MS Paint.
- Photoshop also shows the pixel grid if you zoom in, but MOST tools and brushes are not really suitable for pixel art, in my opinion.
- Kenney.NL aka "Asset Jesus" has a lot of free packs, also a few tools, of which I would recommend KenShape (https://tools.kenney.nl/kenshape/) for pixel art. (edit: I think that only generates 3D voxel models... whoops)